# How do I change a "background-image" without having the image to load for a long time and get a blank backgorund

Tags: jquery, css, image, performance

I have a homepage that changes backgrounds every 2 seconds - a direct change using jQuery with the `background-image`.

The problem with that is that every time that image changes, it has to load and I get a blank screen.

Is there a way to load the images in the background so the browser recognizes the image path or something like this without getting the blank backgrounds?

Not even necessary with jQuery.. if there's a simpler cheat, it will be awesome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

      var count = 1; 


      // Auto Rotate: 
      autoRotate();

      function autoRotate() {
          intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
              rotateNext();
          }, 8000);
      }



      // Move to the next slide: 
      function rotateNext() {


        switch (count) {

          case 3:
              count = 1;           
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-1.jpg)");
              break;

          case 2: 
              count = 3;
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-3.jpg)");  
              break;

          case 1: 
              count = 2; 
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-2.jpg)");  
              break;

        }

      }


     // On Click Right:
      $('.r-arrow').click(function(){
          window.clearInterval(intervalId);
          rotateNext();
          autoRotate();
      });





      function rotatePrev(){

        switch (count) {

          case 1:
              count = 1;           
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-3.jpg)");  
              break;

          case 2: 
              count = 1;
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-1.jpg)");  
              break;

          case 3: 
              count = 2; 
              $('.main').css("background-image", "url(main-2.jpg)");  
              break;

        }

      }




      // On Click Left:
      $(".l-arrow").click(function(){
          window.clearInterval(intervalId);
          rotatePrev();
          autoRotate();
      });







  });

</script>


<div class="main">

  <img src="White_Arrow_top_2.png" class="r-arrow an-arrow" />
  <img src="White_Arrow_top_2.png" class="l-arrow an-arrow" />
</div>
```

Comment: edited my post although i dont think it's needed.@G.L.P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly have the images in the html, use CSS to display:none;

Comment: I was on Chrome 90 and the images still didn't load with display:none. But they did with visibility:hidden.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there's a solution! Checkout this `sample`:

[Background Changing](http://codepen.io/chaitu87/pen/LEzLdo)

Answer (score 1):

You can load the image using a HttpRequest and if the request succeeded the image will be in browser cache. So if you add it will be available without further loading.

But this will only work for images from the same domain.

```
function load(url) {
   $.get(url, function(data){
      console.log('Image is ready to use');
   });
}
```